# ODOO Use invisible attrs on field | Condition: If the number is 0.0

Tags: xml, odoo, invisible

In Odoo when you have an xpath you can add "attrs" to a field invisible, when a condition is met. This works fine.

I have a field DISCOUNT that i want to display on INVOICE/QUOTATION report only if one of the products hold a DISCOUNT value more than 0.0 (i.e - that product has a discount given to it

CODE:

```
<td style="border: 0.5px solid black;background-color:#E6E6E6;">
    <span t-field="l.total_discount" /> 
</td>
```

I want to add:

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('total_discount','=',0.0)]}"
```

But i dont know if this is the correct code above.

Normally, this code should hide all tables of discount if they all equal zero (there's no use of placing a discount block if discount is zero)

REPORT-XML
[image]

INVOICE_VIEW
[image]

Please let me know if am somewhat unclear, in any aspect.

### #

Thanks alot.!

Comment: Did you try it and it did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the whole discount column if there is no discount on the invoice at all would be to have a functional field define that evaluates a boolean, which will tell you if there is even one line in the invoice that has a discount. If there is one line then the boolean would be TRUE. If there is none with a discount then the boolean would be FALSE. Here is the sample code on how to do it.

Define a new field on the model:

```
display_discount_col = fields.Boolean(compute="_display_discount_col")

@api.one
def _display_discount_col(self)
   if line.discount > 0:
       self.display_discount_col = True
       break
```

QWEB code:

```
<t t-if="o.display_discount_col">
    <th>Discount</th>
</t>

<t t-if="o.display_discount_col">
    <td style="border: 0.5px solid black;background-color:#E6E6E6;">
        <span t-field="l.total_discount" /> 
    </td>
</t>
```

I'm not sure if the `discount` field or the `invoice_line` are called what I have mentioned above, you might have to look them up and substitute the correct field names in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `t-if` to specify when the field should be visible.
Put the visible content inside the testing tag, see below:

```
<t t-if="l.total_discount != 0">
    <span t-field="l.total_discount" />
</t>
```

Comment: I tried it -- didnt work :S DISCOUNT still shows, even though its value is set to 0.0